# Системное администрирование для начинающих

Tags: администрирование, книги

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, мне книги для изучения системного администрирования для начинающих. А то не могу найти я. Как для линукс, так же и для Windows.

Answer (score 3):

@navi1893, А что Вы подразумеваете под [системным администрированием](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80)? Для начала определите специализацию, которая Вам больше всего подходит, а затем ищите литературу.  Так или иначе, но знание основ работы ОС, настройки компьютера и сети является обязательным и необходимым. Однако, большую часть знаний можно получить только на практике. Поэтому, если Вы даже не открыли предложенную Вам книгу, то, возможно, Вас заинтересует следующее [издание](http://www.dialektika.com/books/5-8459-0496-X.html), ориентированное на "начинающих" и, в котором более комплексный подход к теме. Также Вам должна помочь [данная книга](http://www.dialektika.com/books/5-8459-0533-8.html).

Ну, а если опустить такое долгое вступление, то вот список книг, которые мне помогли и которые рекомендуют в сети (список не структурирован):

- Кренке - Теория и практика построения БД
- TCP/IP. Сетевое администрирование. 3-е издание. Крейг Хант.
- Столлингс - Современные компьютерные сети
- Таненбаум - Современные ОС
- Мазерс Т. - Администрирование Windows Server 2003/2000 на терминальном сервере
- Стахнов  - Сеть для офиса и Linux-сервер своими руками
- Сергей Бормотов - Системное администрирование на 100%
- Системное администрирование в Linux - Т. Адельштайн, Б. Любанович

На сайте [intuit.ru](http://intuit.ru), можно пройти некоторое бесплатное обучение и получить необходимый минимум знаний. Довольно интересные курсы есть на сайте [lectorium.tv](http://www.lectorium.tv/)

Знание "Модели OSI" приветствуется и поощряется, а в большинстве случаев является обязательным. Топологии сетей, основы построения сетей, работа с серверными ОC.  Заглядывайте на MS techNet, тематические форумы и сайты...Литературы предостаточно, главное: желание учиться и [вот](http://www.dialektika.com/books/5-8459-0533-8.html).

Answer (score 1):

Выскажу ИМХО, вместо Стахнова и Бормотова посоветовал бы Берсенева (там типа краткой подготовки к сдаче LPI 101 и 102) и Немета (там большой труд).Добавил бы к списку по БД - Дейта, но там реально монография. По сетям есть книга и у Таненбаума -  рекомендую. По винде подойдет Windows Server 2008 R2 Моримото. Кроме интуита, если с англ яз нет проблем, то coursera и прочие подобные проекты.И конечно практика, конференции, общение с опытными коллегами, форумы, тематические сайты и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Сам начинающий, тоже в поисках литературы. Читал Ханта, Кенина, смотрел курсы на Интуите и от Специалиста, но самое главное — практика, запомните, книги лишь просто справочники, все познается эмпирическим путем. Удачи!

Answer (score 0):

Вот один из вариантов: "Linux. Все о системах Линукс. Алексей Стахнов."

Comment: @gurzufnet но тут же о самой операционке линукс. Меня интересует **только** системное администрирование

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить, а что же Вы тогда собрались "системно администрировать"?